# Working on Creating Image Gallery in JavaFX. not able to display image properly

Tags: java, javafx, imageview, gallery

I am creating image gallery using javafx. I found many things on internet regarding this but not able to get any suitable help for this issue. I have to create one image gallery like picasa viewer. all the images is in thumbnail view in my image view and after that when I select image that is in pop-up viewer. I did it some code for that but I didn't get proper output. All the images from the folder redraw from the same co-ordinates.
Below is my code and output.

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    String path = "/home/ubuntu/eclipse with liferay/Desktop/imagetest/";

    File folder = new File(path);
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

    for (final File file : listOfFiles) {

            ImageView imageView;
            imageView = createImageView(file);
            imagecontainer.getChildren().addAll(imageView);

    }

}
 private ImageView createImageView(final File imageFile) throws FileNotFoundException, FileNotFoundException, FileNotFoundException, FileNotFoundException {
    // DEFAULT_THUMBNAIL_WIDTH is a constant you need to define  
    // The last two arguments are: preserveRatio, and use smooth (slower) resizing  

    ImageView imageView = null;
    try {

        final Image image;

        image = new Image(new FileInputStream(imageFile), DEFAULT_THUMBNAIL_WIDTH, 0, true, true);
        imageView = new ImageView(image);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(GalleryController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return imageView;

}

}
```

[image: output]

kindly help me to resolve my issue. I want to display images one by one as thumbnail view.

Comment: What is `imageContainer`?

Comment: @James_D : image container is FXML Pane.

Comment: @James_D : sorry man I forget to mention about pane :|

Comment: Well, a `Pane` doesn't do any layout. (See [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/toc.htm)). So if you want to images laid out, you need to use a layout pane that performs layout. You haven't specified how you want that done, so it's hard to answer the question. Maybe read the [layout tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/builtin_layouts.htm#JFXLY102) and pick a layout pane.

Comment: @James_D : I tried with the tiledpane also but could not get all image.. tiled pane just replace image with last image. overwrite all image with last one.. and at the end last image displayed only.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to create a TilePane and add the ImageView's to it. You can have a ScrollPane if needed. A complete example with double click to create a fullscreen preview is shown below. You can of course do necessary changes for creating a FXML :)

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseButton;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.TilePane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ImageGallery extends Application {

    Stage stage;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        stage = primaryStage;
        ScrollPane root = new ScrollPane();
        TilePane tile = new TilePane();
        root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: DAE6F3;");
        tile.setPadding(new Insets(15, 15, 15, 15));
        tile.setHgap(15);

        String path = "/home/ubuntu/eclipse with liferay/Desktop/imagetest/";

        File folder = new File(path);
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

        for (final File file : listOfFiles) {
                ImageView imageView;
                imageView = createImageView(file);
                tile.getChildren().addAll(imageView);
        }


        root.setHbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER); // Horizontal
        root.setVbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.AS_NEEDED); // Vertical scroll bar
        root.setFitToWidth(true);
        root.setContent(tile);

        primaryStage.setWidth(Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds().getWidth());
        primaryStage.setHeight(Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds()
                .getHeight());
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    private ImageView createImageView(final File imageFile) {
        // DEFAULT_THUMBNAIL_WIDTH is a constant you need to define
        // The last two arguments are: preserveRatio, and use smooth (slower)
        // resizing

        ImageView imageView = null;
        try {
            final Image image = new Image(new FileInputStream(imageFile), 150, 0, true,
                    true);
            imageView = new ImageView(image);
            imageView.setFitWidth(150);
            imageView.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {

                    if(mouseEvent.getButton().equals(MouseButton.PRIMARY)){

                        if(mouseEvent.getClickCount() == 2){
                            try {
                                BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
                                ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
                                Image image = new Image(new FileInputStream(imageFile));
                                imageView.setImage(image);
                                imageView.setStyle("-fx-background-color: BLACK");
                                imageView.setFitHeight(stage.getHeight() - 10);
                                imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);
                                imageView.setSmooth(true);
                                imageView.setCache(true);
                                borderPane.setCenter(imageView);
                                borderPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: BLACK");
                                Stage newStage = new Stage();
                                newStage.setWidth(stage.getWidth());
                                newStage.setHeight(stage.getHeight());
                                newStage.setTitle(imageFile.getName());
                                Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane,Color.BLACK);
                                newStage.setScene(scene);
                                newStage.show();
                            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return imageView;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

**Output**

[image]

*This works great when you resize the Window, making the ScrollPane visible, if required.*

Comment: hello.. here in gallery.. only png files are displaying.. jpg not working..?

Comment: All the images used in the above screenshot are of the format `jpg`. If there is something that is not working, please create a new question with a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and link this question/answer in it.

Comment: what about using Scenebuilder to do this?

Comment: @ConnelBLAZE You can use Scene Builder to create a skeleton of the screen, but the various properties needs to be defined via the Controller.

Comment: cos I tried your solution, but it seems `listFiles()` is not supported cos it throws an exception