# Display images dynamically in a ScrollPane

Tags: java, image, javafx, scrollpane

I want to add multiple images in a `ScrollPane` when clicking a button. Now when I click the button a new rectangle is created and fitted with a new image.

The problem is the scrollbar is not displaying when a new image is added.

Here is the code:

```
@FXML
public void handleButtonPause(){
    Rectangle r = new Rectangle();

    if(counterIm==0){
        //Ap1.setMinSize(Sp1.getWidth(), Sp1.getHeight() - 10);
        r.setY(Sp1.getHeight() *((double)1/36));
        r.setWidth(Sp1.getWidth()*0.75);
        rectWidth=r.getWidth();
        r.setHeight(Sp1.getHeight()/6);
        rectHeight=r.getHeight();
    }
    else {
        r.setY(Sp1.getHeight()*((7*counterIm+1)/36));
        r.setWidth(rectWidth);
        r.setHeight(rectHeight);
    }
    r.setX(Sp1.getWidth() / 10);
    r.setArcWidth(20);
    r.setArcHeight(20);

    Ap1.getChildren().add(r);

    Image image = new Image(new      File("C:\\Users\\Manuel\\Desktop\\error.png").toURI().toString());
    r.setFill(new ImagePattern(image));

    Sp1.setVvalue(1);

    counterIm=counterIm+1;
```

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27182323/working-on-creating-image-gallery-in-javafx-not-able-to-display-image-properly. You will get the idea of how to use ImageViews within a ScrollPane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how your composition looks like.

A good approach could be to put the images into a `VBox` and put the `VBox` into the `ScrollPane`.

And check if you have set the VBar Policy of your `SrollPane`:

```
srollbar.setVbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.AS_NEEDED);
```

You can also set the maximal height of the `VBox` to double maximum to make it sure it will always grow vertically:

```
vbox.setMaxHeight(Double.MAX_VALUE);
```