# Media player with interface for java

Tags: java, javafx

Hi there I am working on a small java project that allows me to import, export , play and view. Images , videos and Mp3 files. I am just wondering is there any Java media player interfaces I can embed in my code. I could create my own but if there is one already out there I am sure it would be a lot more stable and save me a lot of time.

By the way I am using javafx with scene builder.

So any help would be great 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To play videos, audio files you should to use [MediaPlayer](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/MediaPlayer.html)
To display Images use [ImageView](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html) with some buttons to change images.

Sample implementation of MediaPlayer [CLICK](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/media-tutorial/playercontrol.htm)

Sample implementation for Album using [ImageViews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27182323/working-on-creating-image-gallery-in-javafx-not-able-to-display-image-properly)

PS. To using SceneBuilder is fine to work faster. But before using this tool, you should to understand how each node works. Try to develop your application without SceneBuilder, it will increase your programming skill. GL

Comment: Thank you sir looks perfect